# MvvmCross 5.2 on Xamarin.Android throws Error 'Assembly' could not be found

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

After upgrading Xamarin.Android project from MvvmCross 5.1 to 5.2 , the code throws an error

```
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Assembly' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

```
public class CustomAndroidPresenter : MvxAndroidViewPresenter
{
    public CustomAndroidPresenter(IEnumerable<Assembly> androidViewAssemblies) : base(androidViewAssemblies)
    {
    }

    public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        if (request != null && request.PresentationValues != null)
        {
            if (request.PresentationValues.ContainsKey("MyCustomFlag"))
            {
                // Get intent from request and set flags to clear backstack.
                var intent = base.CreateIntentForRequest(request);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                base.Show(intent);
                return;
            }
        }
        base.Show(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding `using System.Reflection.Assembly` throws the following errors

Error CS7036 `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'androidViewAssemblies' of 'CustomAndroidPresenter.CustomAndroidPresenter(IEnumerable<Assembly>)'`
Error CS1503 `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Android.Content.Intent' to 'MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest'`

Comment: Try using `base.ShowIntent(intent)` and add `using System.Reflection` instead of `using System.Reflection.Assembly`.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT It throws Error CS7036 `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'androidViewAssemblies' of 'CustomAndroidPresenter.CustomAndroidPresenter(IEnumerable<Assembly>)'`

the full code I have posted here [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103515/updating-mvvmcross-to-5-2-in-xamarin-android-xamarin-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'androidViewAssemblies' of 'CustomAndroidPresenter.CustomAndroidPresenter(IEnumerable)'

Notice that in your `Setup.cs` class, you initialize your `CustomAndroidPresenter` as :

```
var presenter = new CustomAndroidPresenter();
```

But you have add  a constructor in your `CustomAndroidPresenter` class :

```
public CustomAndroidPresenter(IEnumerable<Assembly> androidViewAssemblies) : base(androidViewAssemblies)
{
}
```

So when you initialize `CustomAndroidPresenter`, give it the parameter :

```
var presenter = new CustomAndroidPresenter(AndroidViewAssemblies);
```

> cannot convert from 'Android.Content.Intent' to 'MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest'

Using `base.ShowIntent(intent)` instead of `base.Show(intent)`.

Comment: @Mukteswar Patnaik, have you solved your problem?

Comment: Thank you @york-shen-msft , Yes its solved